# Permissions in Taxonomyhiddenlist in SharePoint 2016 are empty

Tags: permissions, managed-metadata, groups, timer-jobs

I created a site collection with a host Name and in a separate database. After that I deleted the groups/users and added two custom groups "Contributors" and "Visitors".

In one document library I used some managed metadata and when I opened the library in edit mode, I was able to select a term from my term store, but after a second or two the term will disappear from the cell and it will show null.

I started looking around and after a lot of searching I remembered about the taxonomyhiddenlist and I checked the permissions. It was empty. Nothing inside?
How could this be? why the groups were not inserted in the taxonomy hidden list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had almost the same issue as you. I deleted all user groups using powershell and that effected a lot of things. So, try to not delete all groups, but only those that are created by you. Do not delete the once that were created by SharePoint itself.

You will see that the taxonomyHiddenList will contain the custom groups, if you do not delete the OOTB groups.

Let me if this helped you or you need more info.

Comment: Hi Helm, that really helped. I did not remove the groups which were created, like the one about style library, excel... and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the list has unique permissions. If so then you have to manually add the newly created groups to the list.